# Angular ng-repeat item Count after filtered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to get the number of item in ng-repeat after filtered?

but when i use @{{requestlist.length}} code i get total count of records. instead of that i need count of records after filtered by category and text search.

Please hep me

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">

    <label class="checkbox" for="checkboxes-@{{subcatagory.id}}" ng-repeat="subcatagory in subcategories">
        <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-@{{subcatagory.id}}"   ng-click="includeCatagory(subcatagory.id)" type="checkbox">
        @{{subcatagory.titel}}
    </label>

    <div class="eol-layout-s3" ng-repeat="request in requestlist | filter:catagoryFilter | filter:search | orderBy:'titel':true">
        <div id="jobDesc-bd">
            <a href="/request/@{{request.id}}" >
                <strong>
                @{{request.titel | characters:30}} 
                </strong>
            </a>

            <small>
                @{{request.message | characters:200}}  
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
<h2>count: @{{requestlist.length}}</h2>
```

**Angular**

```
$http.get('/api/subcategories/{{$seller->category_id}}/').success(function(subcategories){
        $scope.subcategories = subcategories;
    });
    $http.get('/api/requests/list/').success(function(requests){
        $scope.requestlist = requests;
    });

    $scope.catagoryFilter = function(cat) {
                if ($scope.catagoryIncludes.length > 0) {
                    if ($.inArray(cat.subcategorie_id, $scope.catagoryIncludes) < 0)
                        return;
                }

                return cat;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify

```
ng-repeat="request in requestlist 
               | filter:catagoryFilter | filter:search | orderBy:'titel':true"
```

To

```
ng-repeat="request in (filterResult = (requestlist | filter:catagoryFilter 
| filter:search | orderBy:'titel':true))"
```

length can be accessed by `{{filterResult.length}}` in template or `$scope.filterResult.length` in controller.

**Note:** you might want to initialize `$scope.filterResult = [];` some times it gives undefined errors.

Notice that you can store the filtered result by assigning the result after filter in some variable like in above example (`filterResult`). Then you can use this model `"filterResult"`. Even in controller `$scope.filterResult` is available to use.